# arules isolating lhs and rhs

Tags: r, arules

So here is the example:

```
library(arules)
data(Adult)
rules <- apriori(Adult,parameter = list(maxlen = 2,minlen=2))
inspect(head(rules,3))


 lhs                         rhs                              support confidence     lift
1 {relationship=Unmarried} => {capital-loss=None}            0.1019819  0.9719024 1.019537
2 {occupation=Sales}       => {race=White}                   0.1005282  0.8920785 1.043314
3 {occupation=Sales}       => {native-country=United-States} 0.1039679  0.9226017 1.028055
```

I want to create a data.table with 2 columns, one called lhs and the other rhs where I have stored the lhs and rhs values of my rules like this:

```
lhs                        rhs
relationship=Unmarried    capital-loss=None
occupation=Sales          race=White
occupation=Sales          native-country=United-States
```

I would swear that I did it once starting with `a<-as.data.table(inspect(rules))` on windows but on my mac that doesnt work... What do you suggest?

Comment: Are you able to access individual columns? (`inspect(rules)$lhs`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
library(arules)
library(data.table)
data(Adult)
rules <- apriori(Adult,parameter = list(maxlen = 2,minlen=2))
r <- head(rules,3)
```

If `as.data.table(inspect(r))` does not work (it does on my machine, Win7 x64, R 3.2.2 & `packageVersion("arules")` beeing `1.3.0`), then maybe try

```
f <- function(x, fun) unlist(as(fun(x), "list"))
( dt <- data.table(lhs=f(r, lhs), rhs=f(r, rhs)) )
#                       lhs                          rhs
# 1: relationship=Unmarried            capital-loss=None
# 2:       occupation=Sales                   race=White
# 3:       occupation=Sales native-country=United-States
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I intended this to be done...

```
library(arules)
data(Adult)
rules <- apriori(Adult,parameter = list(maxlen = 2,minlen=2))

data.frame(lhs = labels(lhs(rules), setStart = "", setEnd = ""), 
           rhs = labels(rhs(rules), setStart = "", setEnd = ""))
```

Comment: This isn't working when I have a "Large rules (652.5 Kb)" result from `apriori()`. The `write` function in `arules` is successful, but I can't get LHS and RHS separated. I even tried `DATAFRAME(rules, separate = TRUE)` which gives a `Error in data.frame(LHS = factor(antes, levels = unique(antes)), RHS = factor(conseqs,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0` error. Is it possible that the "Large" object breaks the `lhs()`, etc. accesses?

Comment: You need to post a complete example that replicates the problem.